Implementation of a tag <link rel="preload" as="image" href="image.png"> in header of JoomGallery
I would like to implement preload link into the head of the JoomGallery like
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="image_name.png"> 

Unfortunatelly the following code does not work:
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="<?php echo $this->image->img_src; ?>">

I assume the reason for it is not intialiasated object/not imported class within head.
How can I develop it?

On Joomla 4.0 or later, you can use Joomla\CMS\Document\PreloadManager class to manage preloads. It will use the Link header instead of <link> element. You can get it from the document instance:
$this->getDocument()->getPreloadManager()->preload($this->image->img_src, ['as' => 'image']);

You may need to prepend the root URI, if image src doesn't contain it yet.
On J3 you can use document's addHeadLink() method to add a <link> element:
$this->document->addHeadLink($this->image->img_src, 'preload', 'rel', ['as' => 'image]);


I am not sure of your img_src, is it not src only ?
Have you done a print_r($this) for control ?

"$this->image->img_src;" delivers a link to the detail image like "/images/joomgallery/details/name_of_rubric/file_name.png"

Ok, I din't remember this exact syntax
